# チャット機能: 管理人画面で作成した関数をdeveloper toolのconsoleで確認しても、全てnot definedになる。

Tags: javascript, firebase, console

チャット機能を作成していて、ユーザー画面と管理人画面を作成しました。
Firebaseのセットアップを別のものに変え、Firebaseでの設定も以前のセットアップと変わらないよう設定しました。
以前のセットアップでは、ユーザー画面は全て匿名自動ログインで、管理人画面では、管理人１人だけユーザー追加でメールアドレスとパスワード認証をログイン時に必要としていました。

Firebaseのセットアップを別のものに変えて、一つ以前と違う設定は、ユーザー追加で２人メールアドレスとパスワードで管理人としてログインするようにしました。管理人になる人（知人）にこのチャット機能を提供するためです。

Firebaseでもセットアップを別のものに変えても、ツリーも表示され、きちんと投稿されたメッセージも監視されています。管理人画面でも投稿は表示され、メッセージも送れます。

ですが、ログイン機能に問題が発生したことに気がついたため（管理人画面でログアウトすると、ユーザー画面でもなぜかconsoleを見るとログアウトしているようで投稿できない。）、コードを編集しようとし、原因を調べるためにdeveloper tooのconsoleでどの関数に問題があるか調べようとしました。しかし、管理人画面のjsファイルのみ、どの関数も

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: 関数 is not defined   at <anonymous>:1:13   VM2455:1
```

と出るので、解決策やアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか...?

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　ここでは自分の質問は質問文の下の「編集」から自由に書き直せますので、お試しください。コメントは後から来た人が読みにくいので、なるべく編集で追記してくださるとありがたいです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/74247